# Look up any callable from dotted string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

There are plenty of answers on how to look up a function or class in python from a dotted string (eg `lookup('my.module.some_function')`) but as far as I can see they all assume the first part of the string is a module, and final part is something at the module level.

I'm particularly looking for a solution that can handle static class methods (example below) and module level functions, but it seems like there should be a python builtin or a simple function using builtins that can handle all cases (bonus points for nested classes!).

An answer that works for all common versions would be ideal. If its not possible to handle this generically, I think an answer that demonstrates the mechanisms to load a function vs a staticmethod would be sufficient, and future readers of the question could use that as a guide on how to roll their own solution that handles the cases they require.

For example, given the following definitions:

```
# In /my/module.py

def my_func():
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__():
        pass

    @staticmethod  # or @classmethod
    def factory():
        return MyClass()
```

I'm after a lookup function that supports the following:

```
f = lookup('my.module.my_func')
f()  # Equivalent to calling my_func()

f = lookup('my.module.MyClass')
f()  # Equivalent to calling MyClass()

f = lookup('my.module.MyClass.factory')
f()  # Equivalent to calling MyClass.factory()
```

Comment: The function that does that is `eval()`, so you probably have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: All the answers I've looked at for the function-in-a-module case avoid using `eval()` in favour of `importlib`. I just assumed there was a good reason for this - but if not, then `eval()` (combined with checks that you have a dotted string and not arbitrary code) certainly would be simple. Also, `f = eval('my.module.my_func')` does not work, so it appears its not the function you are looking for. Its not clear to me how you munge the string or `eval` statements to handle all cases without side-effects such as importing modules into the calling scope.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not at all pretty, but here is something you can use:

```
from importlib import import_module

def lookup(st):
    # first we have to find the maximal module path
    # in the provided string, so we work right to
    # left across the dot pieces.
    pieces = st.split('.')
    n = len(pieces)
    module = None
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1
        rg = pieces[:n]
        # if we haven't been able to resolve a module, break out of the loop
        if not rg: break
        module_name = '.'.join(rg)
        try:
            # once we find a matching module, break out of this loop
            module = import_module(module_name)
            break
        except ImportError:
            pass
    if not module:
        raise ImportError('No module specified in %s' % st)
    # once we have the specified module, we can just repeatedly
    # call getattr to find the specified function or class.  This 
    # should work for classes, first-class functions, and class 
    # functions.  I am not sure about static class functions.
    result = module
    for x in pieces[n:]:
        result = getattr(result, x, None)
        if not result:
            raise AttributeError('could not resolve %s' % x)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid I'd have to do some iteration over the string to discover where the module part ended. I'll give your answer a whirl in the next 24 hours and accept if it works.